# Request timeout error on calling WCF webservice from webservice client on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have made a simple WCF web-service and putted a simple string method that returns "Hellow "  + name you have passed as parameter to it in my ASP.NET C# web-application and deployed it to my localhost. Then made a client application and added web-reference of the web service i have deployed recently on localhost. Now I am running client application and passing my name in the object of web-service class. I am getting request timeout error. I have tried by setting timeout property -1 as infinite and keep running request but did not get response even after 20 minutes. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Can you post your client and server configuration?

Comment: Solved it myself.. actually I was adding localhost service via "Add WebRefernce.." in the client project, Issue is get solved by adding localhost service via "Add ServiceReference.."

Comment: ok Nice! now answer this, and don't forget to mark it as answer, so the question gets removed from the queue ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it myself.. actually I was adding localhost service via "Add WebRefernce.." in the client project, Issue is get solved by adding localhost service via "Add ServiceReference.."