# Accessing a Web Service hosted on Client PC using ASP.net Web App

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, web-applications, client-server

I have a client pc which accesses my website (CRM). The client PC is running an API toolkit as a background service and is accessed via SOAP calls, nothing tricky just standard Web Reference and some server-side methods to invoke the API toolkit's methods.

Everything is great when running the web application on my local IIS. The reference in the web.config points the address to localhost:8080 which is the address of the server. Having a custom web.config with a dynamic service url for all clients is not an option. I tried setting the url property so when the web application is started it retrieves the client machine's hostname and change the url property of the service reference however, this would only work if all the computers were on the company domain. The below reference is what works on my local pc, changing it manually to my hostname fails when run from the server and not my local dev IIS.

```
<applicationSettings>
<CRMIntegration.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="CRMIntegration_AgentBridgeService_WebserviceAgentBridgeService"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://localhost:8080/AgentBridge</value>
  </setting>
</CRMIntegration.Properties.Settings>
```

Despite several different ways of trying to map the service to the proper client it still fails to work.

(I'm thinking):
Create a method or function to set the correct path to the client pc's web service, strip out the web.config reference and write an extend the web reference class to override where the generated reference.cs is getting it's url property.

I have seen examples of this being done with the exact same API toolkit by several SaaS CRM's so I know it can be done. I don't have a clue what direction to look in after searching for a couple days.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found this post which seems along the lines of what I am dealing with. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412776/request-timeout-error-on-calling-wcf-webservice-from-webservice-client-on-localh however, I do not understand how a service reference vs. web reference would affect this aside from asp.net 2.0 vs 3.5+ perhaps they are handled differently. I'll give it a try and leave the question open unless it resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than expected. I had two routes: use jquery with xml or an undocumented querystring in the api. I chose the querystring and all is well.